# I don't know whether the sequence converges

Tags: sequences-and-series

We have $a_0 = x_2\in [0,A]$ and $a_{n+1} = (A−a_n)/2$. Prove that this sequence converges to $A/3$. And then prove the same for the sequences $a_{2k}$ and $a_{2k+1}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: write $a_n = A/3 + b_n$. Then $$a_{n+1} = (A - a_n) / 2 = A / 3 - b_n / 2 = A/3 + b_{n+1}.$$

Alternative proof: the function $x \mapsto (A - x) / 2$ is a contraction and so by Banach's fixed-point theorem has a unique fixed point $ x = (A - x) / 2$ and so $x = A/3$.

Comment: Actually, we don't need Banach here: it's enough to observe that the graph of the function is a line not parallel with the line $y=x$ and so intersects it in a unique point.

Comment: @Marek One does not really need all that to determine the asymptotics of $b_n=b_0/2^n$...

Comment: @did: what exactly are you referring to (I mentioned Banach's theorem just for fun)? Also, your expression for $b_n$ is not correct...

Comment: @Marek I referred to what you wrote in your comment (what else?). (Right, $b_n=(-1)^nb_0/2^n$.)

Comment: Nice answer (+1). I wrote up a similar answer before I read yours, oh well :-)